# gradle set absolute path value for a keystore file

Tags: android, gradle, groovy

I'd like to save my keystore **outside** the project directory. I don't want to store filepaths  inside the repository so I delegated the values to appropriate gradle variables in `~/.gradle/gradle.properties`
I can't get gradle to accept an absolute path like:
`/Users/username/.gradle/keystores/project/release.key`
or
`~/.gradle/keystores/project/release.key`

I tried:
`storeFile file(RELEASE_STORE_FILE)`
and 
`storeFile new File(RELEASE_STORE_FILE)`

none of them seems to work, however.

How can I pass an absolute path value to the keystore file through `RELEASE_STORE_FILE` variable?

```
android {
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file(RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
            storePassword RELEASE_STORE_PASS
            keyAlias RELEASE_ALIAS
            keyPassword RELEASE_KEY_PASS
        }
    }
}
```

and the `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` file:

```
RELEASE_STORE_FILE=/Users/username/.gradle/keystores/project/release.key
RELEASE_STORE_PASS=******
RELEASE_ALIAS=******
RELEASE_KEY_PASS=******
```

In short: I want to pass an absolute path value to gradle.

Comment: What do you mean you can't get gradle to accept s path? What happens when you do?

Comment: sorry for the confusion - it was probably my configuration fault. I ended up using another interesting solution from Tim Rose.

Comment: I'm really sure that it'll use the absolute path if you use `storeFile file(RELEASE_STORE_FILE)`. Please make sure that you didn't add double quotation or single quotation before and after the path.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up using an interesting solution from [this](https://www.timroes.de/2013/09/22/handling-signing-configs-with-gradle/) site.

The idea is to keep variables in a separate folder which is **stored on a remote repository**.

In `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` file you put:

```
Keys.repo=/Users/username/.signing
```

where `Keys.repo` is the local path to your remote repository.

Later on in `/Users/username/.signing/YourProjectName.properties` you have:

```
RELEASE_STORE_FILE=/YourProjectName/release.keystore //in fact it's a relative path
RELEASE_STORE_PASS=xxxxx
RELEASE_ALIAS=xxxxx
RELEASE_KEY_PASS=xxxxx
```

You need to store `release.keystore` file in `/Users/username/.signing/YourProjectName/release.keystore` path

The configuration is used in the following way:

```
android {
    signingConfigs {
        debug { /* no changes - usual config style */ }
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty("Keys.repo")) {
                def projectPropsFile = file(project.property("Keys.repo") + "/YourProjectName.properties")
                if (projectPropsFile.exists()) {
                    Properties props = new Properties()
                    props.load(new FileInputStream(projectPropsFile))

                    storeFile file(file(project.property("Keys.repo") + props['RELEASE_STORE_FILE']))
                    storePassword props['RELEASE_STORE_PASS']
                    keyAlias props['RELEASE_ALIAS']
                    keyPassword props['RELEASE_KEY_PASS']
                }
            } else {
                println "======================================================="
                println "[ERROR] - Please configure release-compilation environment - e.g. in ~/.signing  directory"
                println "======================================================="
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I got around this by using a **symlink**

1. Create symlink `keystore.lnk` in the app module

   ln -s [path-to-keystore] keystore.lnk
2. Then use `keystore.lnk` in `gradle.properties`

   RELEASE_STORE_FILE=keystore.lnk (don't use quotes)

Now your gradle instructions will work.

Answer (score 3):

Found solution there: https://gist.github.com/gabrielemariotti/6856974

Briefly, you should parse file that contains path to keystore properly. Modify yours module's gradle with next lines. First, this is how to create signingConfigs based on keystore.properties file content:

```
signingConfigs
    {
        release
        {
            def Properties props = new Properties()
            def propFile = new File('path/to/your/keystore.properties') //absolute path to keystore.properties
            if (propFile.canRead())
            {
                props.load(new FileInputStream(propFile))

            if (props != null && props.containsKey('STORE_FILE') && props.containsKey('STORE_PASSWORD') &&
                    props.containsKey('KEY_ALIAS') && props.containsKey('KEY_PASSWORD'))
            {
                android.signingConfigs.release.storeFile = file(props['STORE_FILE']) 
                android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword = props['STORE_PASSWORD']
                android.signingConfigs.release.keyAlias = props['KEY_ALIAS']
                android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword = props['KEY_PASSWORD']
            }
            else
            {
                println 'keystore.properties found but some entries are missing'
                android.buildTypes.release.signingConfig = null
            }
        }
        else
        {
            println 'keystore.properties not found'
            android.buildTypes.release.signingConfig = null
        }
    }
}
```

And then add signingConfig to yours release buildType:

```
buildTypes 
{
    ...
    release 
    {
        ...
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release            
    }
}
```

Example of keystore.properties file for this solution:

```
STORE_FILE=absolute//path//to//store
STORE_PASSWORD=yourPass
KEY_PASSWORD=keysPass
KEY_ALIAS=aliasName
```

This has worked for me (Android Studio 3.0.1, Gradle 4.1, Windows 10).

Answer (score 1):

In my case (macOS) with my `local_store.keystore` saved in `Users/<username>` and the path to the keystore configured in the `gradle.properties` file as:

```
RELEASE_STORE_FILE=Users/<username>/local_store.keystore
```

I was getting the following error:

```
> Keystore file 
'/Users/<username>/Documents/MyProject/android/app/Users/<username>/local_store.keystore' 
not found for signing config 'release'.
```

so the path set in the `gradle.properties` was added to the relative path of the `build.gradle` file (notice duplicated `/Users/<username>`).

I fixed that by specifying the path to the keystore with a few `../` to point to the right location in the `Users/<username>` folder.

This is how it should look in the `gradle.properties` file:

```
RELEASE_STORE_FILE=../../../../../local_store.keystore
```

No modifications are required to the `build.gradle` file.

Answer (score 0):

I use this on a Mac

> ```
> signingConfigs {
>     debug {
>         storeFile file(System.env.HOME + '/.android/debug.keystore')
>         storePassword 'android'
>         keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
>         keyPassword 'android'
>     }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

By chance I ended up implementing something similar to Mikhail Avdeev's answer, but in order to provide an example for Kotlin based buildscripts, too, here's my solution anyway:

Add `id("com.sidneysimmons.gradle-plugin-external-properties") version "2.0.1" apply false` to your project-level build.gradle.kts ([plugin source here](https://gitlab.com/h2292/gradle-plugin-external-properties))

For your module-level build.gradle.kts, use this:

```
import com.android.build.api.dsl.ApkSigningConfig

plugins {
    // [... all your other plugins]
    id("com.sidneysimmons.gradle-plugin-external-properties")
}

externalProperties {
    propertiesFileResolver(file("signing.properties"))
}

android {
    signingConfigs {
        named("debug") {
            if (checkExternalSigningConfig()) {
                applyExternalSigningConfig()
            } else {
                // Use the default debug keystore if no configuration has been specified
                defaultConfig.signingConfig
            }
        }
        create("release") {
            if (checkExternalSigningConfig()) {
                applyExternalSigningConfig()
                // automatically add the signingConfig to your
                // build config if the configuration file is valid
                android.buildTypes.getByName("release").signingConfig = this
            }
        }
    }
}

fun ApkSigningConfig.checkExternalSigningConfig(): Boolean {
    return props.exists("$name.keyStore") &&
            file(props.get("$name.keyStore")).exists() &&
            props.exists("$name.storePassword") &&
            props.exists("$name.keyAlias") &&
            props.exists("$name.keyPassword")
}

fun ApkSigningConfig.applyExternalSigningConfig() {
    storeFile = file(props.get("$name.keyStore"))
    storePassword = props.get("$name.storePassword")
    keyAlias = props.get("$name.keyAlias")
    keyPassword = props.get("$name.keyPassword")
}
```

Place a file called `signing.properties` in your module directory (`app` or whatever), where you can happily use absolute paths (Windows example in this case):

```
debug.keyStore=\\C:\\Path\\to\\keystore\\file
debug.storePassword=your_password
debug.keyAlias=your_keyAlias
debug.keyPassword=your_password

release.keyStore=\\C:\\Path\\to\\keystore\\file
release.storePassword=your_password
release.keyAlias=your_keyAlias
release.keyPassword=your_password
```